# Bandwidth of the product of two functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two functions with finite bandwidth, i.e., the support of their Fourier transform has length $a$ and $b$, respectively. How can we show that the bandwidth of $f(x)g(x)$ is upper bounded by $a+b$? It's not direct to see this result by simply doing the Fourier transform $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)e^{-iwx}dx$.

Comment: Use the fact that the Fourier transform of the product is proportional to the convolution of the Fourier transforms.

Comment: Aha, @Gonçalo Thank you for your comment. I've noticed the convolution theorem before but didn't see it can really be used to solve this question. After I get more information about the idea of convolution, the result is direct. For future references, one can refer [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170329002009/https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~wjh/teaching/Fourier/documents/convolution.pdf)

Comment: Add a little more information for future reference. The fact mentioned in the comment is different from the typical convolutional theorem. One needs to prove it. That is, $F^{-1}\left( f*g \right) \propto F^{-1}\left( f \right) F^{-1}\left( g \right) $ where $F^{-1}$ is the inverse of the Fourier transform.